Crosscompiling with emscripten and meson - Failed at setup phase with ERROR: ld.wasm does not support shared libraries
I have a working meson build (for native builds) that I am trying to use with emscripten.
meson setup exits with an error code and the last message is:
ERROR: ld.wasm does not support shared libraries
This is normal since emscripten is not supposed to compile dynamic.
My meson.build is setup for both dynamic and static, which I select based on some custom command line arguments. For native build, I am successfully linking static or dynamic. I can even not generate the executable and only get the static library.
I added message throughout the meson.build files and I see that setup completes until the end. But the error about the linker is preventing the successful completion and the ninja.build is essentially empty.
Not sure where to go from here.

My mistake. The meson.build (which is from an open source) was using some linker option that are only for dynamic linking, thus causing the error.
Removing that option resolved the issue.

Could you specify which option you removed?
